# One or more output arguments not assigned during call to mdwt - Wavelet Transform

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, wavelet

I'm trying to filter an image using Wavelet Tranform. I tried to use the function `mdwt` from here : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6391-wavelets-based-denoising/content/mdwt.m, and the other functions from this link , like this :

```
img = imread('A10T_1.jpg');       
h = daubcqf(4,'min');
L = 1;
y = mdwt(img,h,L);
```

The problem is that at the last line I get : `One or more output arguments not assigned during call to`, `Error in => y = mdwt(img,h,L);`

Where is the problem? The function `mdwt` contains only the declaration, nothing more, and I can see that's the problem. Can anyone help me to solve me this ? Or there is any other method to filter an image using Wavelet Transform without using these functions ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

Now I'm tring to show the image denoised usind wavelet Transform with this code :

```
RGB = imread('small.jpg');
 J = imnoise(RGB,'salt & pepper',0.05);h = daubcqf(6);  
      noisyLena = J;
      figure; colormap(gray); imagesc(RGB); title('Original Image');
       figure; colormap(gray); imagesc(noisyLena); title('Noisy Image'); 
%       Denoise lena with the default method based on the DWT
      [denoisedLena,xn,opt1] = denoise(noisyLena,h);
      figure; colormap(gray); imagesc(denoisedLena); title('denoised Image');
```

but I get the error

```
??? The matrix row dimension must be of size m*2^(L)

Error in ==> denoise at 171
  [xd , LL]= mdwt(double(i),h,L);

Error in ==> wavelet_start at 20
      [denoisedLena,xn,opt1] = denoise(noisyLena,h);
```

where denoise function is this : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6391-wavelets-based-denoising/content/denoise.m

where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the files in that collection are MEX files, written in C.  The M-file is only for documentation, but since you don't have the MEX file compiled, MATLAB is trying to run the M-file for the code itself.  You need to build them for your platform before you can run the code.

Try reading the INSTALL.txt documentation provided, which amounts to running "compile" in that directory.

Your next challenge will be that this code is old, and you may have compatibility issues with more recent MATLAB versions.  But try it, see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done everything from install.txt but now when I run this code I get a Segmentation violation and a big list of ... it looks like this : http://pastebin.com/CwpUHPLR . It is possible that my matlab version is too new. What do you think ?

Comment: Well, since the MEX file compiled, there are no obvious compatibility issues.  Chances are, the input validation is not complete, and you're passing in something unexpected.  Actually, it looks like the function needs a double array, and you're probably passing in an integer array.  Also, the DWT of a 3-channel image doesn't make any sense, so passing in a 3D array like you are probably causes more trouble.

Comment: The DWT of a color image doesn't make sense, so you need to figure out  what you want your algorithm to do.  Maybe convert to grayscale.  Then convert your 2D array to double before calling the wavelet function.

Comment: I put i=rgb2gray(img), y = mdwt(i,h, L) but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: You still didn't convert to double.  y = mdwt(double(i), h, L)

Comment: Thanks Peter, this works. :) Can you see my edit? Maybe you can help me with this new error.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are trying to use is defined as

```
function [y,L] = mdwt(x,h,L);
```

When you call the function in your code you are only assigning the first output-parameter

```
y = ...
```

The function has two output parameters,

```
[y,L] = ...
```

you have to assign both when using the function.

Comment: This is not the problem. With [y, L]= .. I get the same thing. What Peter said is right, but I still can run my code.

Comment: Ok, I've only used the Wavelet Toolbox, which should let you do what you want. But I guess you don't have access to it?

Comment: No, I don't have access to it :| I'm tring to use this code but I get this http://pastebin.com/CwpUHPLR :(

Comment: I'd follow Peters advice about reading the install.txt file then. My experience with 3rd party matlab code is fairly limited.